# permgen exception.. tried a number of suggestions but to no avail

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, permgen

I am getting out of memory exception in eclipse related to permgen.. i have tried changing the values in the ini file but thats not helping. I took reference from the various related posts in this site. My machine config is corei5, 8 GB RAM. The development i am doing requires me to run Tomcat and an android application which would send http requests to this tomcat server.. i am posting the ini i am using right now.. can anyone help please?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms1700m
-Xmx1700m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1700m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

Comment: Is Eclipse _itself_ dying with the permgen error, or your build target (AKA your application running within Eclipse)? If it's the latter, you need to visit the JRE tab in your Run/Debug configuration and add -XX:MaxPermSize=??? there. BTW, 1700m is a _huge_ value; I would suggest something more like 128m.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 1700m is indeed a huge value to be having. I guess its your application itself which is throwing the permgen error, and not eclipse as such at startup.
If it is your application that is throwing the error, add the following options to JAVA_OPTS in catalina.bat file. (Inside Tomcat's bin directory).

```
-XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Also, just go through your application, and make sure that there are no classes which are being continuously loaded for every http request. This might be the reason you are getting this error. May be you could check the server logs to see which all classes are getting loaded for every request.You may enable these logs by adding the following options to JAVA_OPTS.

```
-XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading
```

And if it is related with eclipse, and not with your application, you may add

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=<value>
```

to the vm parameters in the launch configuration (Run As-> Run Configurations-> )